# Auto Edit Files After Uploading On Server

Tags: php, javascript, html

One thing has stucked me. I am planning to get into some scripts that automatically edits a file upon upload.

I mean like. I have a form, someone uploads an html. The script edits some section of the html and then provide the user with the new edited html.

Like we see in the online converters. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: It'd be a lot better if you give us more information on what you had to change into what it should be changed. Give examples!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Upload your file.
2. [Read the contents of the file](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents).
3. [Interpret and Change those contents](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).
4. [Replace the old content with the changed content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).
5. Display new content to user.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this still depends on what kind of file and what kind of edit.

But the general idea is:

1. Save a tmp file
2. Parse the file with the right parser
3. Output the new file
4. remove the tmp file if needed
5. notify user it's done

Without more info it is hard to provide more advise..

Comment: hi I am new to it so can you explain a bit more, it would be more helpful if you include an example. Thanks a lot :)